Plex problem newbie
As an absolute nitwit with the terminal:
How do I give Plex access to my USB HD's. Can it be done with a GUI app? Or else,how?
Ruud

Already installed?

Providing your Ubuntu product & release details allows us to know what software & what defaults your system has, currently you've not told us much; why make us guess.  I'd add your USB HDDs to your file-system table as it works on almost all systems (using appropriate directory for your unstated product & unstated Plex install as that does matter!) ; ie. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Fstab  as that will work on Server, Desktop & almost all installs.

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Start from the beginning: tell us what Ubuntu you are running, tell us what you are trying to do, where your Plex library is, where your USB HD is (output of mount perhaps), what kind of "access", what error you are getting that makes you think you need to give special access, and then we can take it from there. As it stands, we have no idea what you have done or what you need.

I use Mint. I used to use Plex, when I installed it then there was an option there was an option to give reading access to external drives. I started to use Jellyfin because of the open source. Plex has some qualities that I like better. I re-installed Plex but cannot read the files of the external drives. I can see the drive and that's it.

media/ruud/AchtA is what I see Mounting point is /mnt/usb-WD_Elements_25A3_434133365454424C-0:0-part1

Only Ubuntu and official flavors of Ubuntu are on-topic here, refer https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic where you'll find other SE sites where you question will be welcome if you don't want to use a Linux Mint forum. (One advantage of Ubuntu is its many support options, you opted for Linux Mint so take advantage of its support options, or SE Unix & Linux found in the on-topic link)
